# How to combine Django import_export with list_display in admin.py?

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm new to Django, and I want to know how to combine import_export module with `list_display` in `admin.py`?

For example:

When I use list_display to display two fields (id and IP), below codes in `admin.py` works fine, but I can't see the import export widgets:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import SwitchModel

@admin.register(SwitchModel)
class SwitchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','IP')
```

[image]

When I use below codes, I can see the import and export widgets, but I can no longer see the two fields (id and IP):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import SwitchModel
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class SwitchModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = SwitchModel

class SwitchModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = SwitchModelResource

admin.site.register(SwitchModel, SwitchModelAdmin)
```

[image]

I tried to combine the two sets of codes together like below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import SwitchModel
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

@admin.register(SwitchModel)
class SwitchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','IP')

class SwitchModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = SwitchModel

class SwitchModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = SwitchModelResource

admin.site.register(SwitchModel, SwitchModelAdmin)
```

Then I kept receiving the below Error:

[image]

How can I have `list_display` and `import_export` widgets work together? Could anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you just need to add your `list_display` options to your admin class.

```py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from import_export import resources
    from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

    from .models import SwitchModel
    

    class SwitchModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            model = SwitchModel
    

    class SwitchModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('id', 'IP')
        resource_class = SwitchModelResource
    

    admin.site.register(SwitchModel, SwitchModelAdmin)
```

It's also worth noting that it's good practice to use lowercase field names for models, so `ip` rather than `IP`.

Perhaps have a read through some [best practice info](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-best-practices-models).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have found the answer on YouTube. But I will also have a try of your codes.

Comment: @ParryWang Yeah, that's the same as what I've said.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on Youtube:

Below codes achieve what I want:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import SwitchModel
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

@admin.register(SwitchModel)
class SwitchModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'IP')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import SwitchModel
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

// this class helps you add import export options to SwitchModel in admin
class SwitchModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = SwitchModel
        exclude = ('id',) // this statement is to exclude the id field that is added by default, not excluding id gave me error

@admin.register(SwitchModel)
class SwitchAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = SwitchModelResource
    list_display = ('id','IP')
```

You can also add `SwitchModelResource` class to another file named `resource.py` as it is suggested.
Sorry I cannot explain in depth since I started learning `import_export` recently.
I hope the comments help you understand your errors.